# Transient and steady state of marginally stable system

Tags: stability, transient, steady-state

I know that if a system is asymptotically stable then after infinite time its output contains only characteristic of input signal and it is also known as steady state and there are no transient component left in output, and if system is asymptotically unstable then whatever will be input is its output will become infinite after infinite time so we can say that it doesn't reach at steady state and it's transient components become infinitely large

but what about transient and steady state in marginally stable systems?

Because in marginally stable systems even after infinite time it contains both inputs characteristics and systems characteristics so what exactly transient and steady state components will be?

I don't know whether I understand transient and steady state conditions properly (whatever I explained above) or it is just poorly defined in books?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability#System_response  "*there will in general be no final steady-state output*".

Comment: "*its output contains only characteristic of input signal and it is also known as steady state*" I think this is not the definition of *steady state*. You seem to be equating natural response to transient response and forced response to steady state. This may not be correct.

Comment: The "steady state" of a marginally stable system will be its natural frequency, i.e. this is an oscillator. Such systems have poles on the jw axis, so the output will have a complex exponential for all time, that is stable in the sense the amplitude is constant.